# Codeigniter & HMVC Controller Structure for 3rd degree Controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, hmvc

I'm using HMVC extension on Codeigniter. My problem is mostly about url structure and don't want to make routing.

HMVC works with:

```
/modules
  /manage
    /controllers
       /language
          language.php
```

on this URL: **site_url/manage/language**

but not with this structure:

```
/modules
   /manage
      /controllers
         /language
            /listing.php
```

on this URL: **site_url/manage/language/listing**

Comment: does the listing class extend the MX_Controller class

Comment: Yes it extends MX_Controller class.

Comment: tried it out, i guess its not possible to get up 3rd degree controllers, you might have to mess with the loader library to look deeper for 3rd degree controllers

Comment: lol I guessed it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
/modules
   /manage
      /controllers
         /language.php
         /listing.php
```

If you need separate more the methods, you must create another module.

Comment: Sorry, but this structure will bring me to **/manage/language** and **/manage/listing** pages. That's not I wanted to do.